Thermostat Wiring for Navien Heating
I have a NCB250/150H unit for space heating and wanted to know if it's possible to connect 2 low voltage thermostat wires or splice them into one and connect to a single thermostat terminal zone (only R/W)? What would happen if both thermostats were to call for heat? Would this cause issues ?
